# Flip the order of a date string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, datetime

I have a list that I need input into this function: `'11h00', '5-11-2019', 'iXicoZe', 'Drones'`
but the function only accepts if the date is written like this: `'11h00', '2019-11-2019', 'iXicoZe', 'Drones'`

```py
def dateFromString(datestr):
    datestr=datestr.strip()
    return date(int(datestr[:2]), int(datestr[3:5]), int(datestr[6:10]))
```

Comment: `2019-11-2019` cannot be the correct output; please edit to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Split on hyphens, reverse, then join with hyphens:

```py
def reverse_date_string(s):
    return '-'.join(reversed(s.split('-')))
```

Example:

```py
>>> reverse_date_string('5-11-2019')
'2019-11-5'
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you want the date in `Y-m-d` and not `2019-11-2019` that is no-sense, you can use datetime

```
from datetime import datetime

old_date = datetime.strptime('5-11-2019', '%d-%m-%Y')
new_date_str = old_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%-d')
```

The new date is `2019-11-5`, so the reversed date

Edit: be careful putting `'%Y-%m-%-d'` and not `'%Y-%m-%d'`, the additional `-` is necessary to exclude the leading zero in the day. Don't know why my answer was edited.

Comment: The last line `old_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%-d')` was edited without my approve, removing the `-` before `d`. I don't know why, the `-` before `d` (so that `%-d`) is necessary otherwise the day will be with the leading zero that is not what OP wants.